# Iphone Navigation problems

Tags: iphone, navigation, uitabbarcontroller

i am designing an app which requires the following structure

- Tab Bar controller (3 tabs always available, Home, photos and setting)

  First tab (Home tab)

  -Contains a view controller with 5 buttons (News,events,offers, maps and feed)

  - Clicking on any of the above button should load another view which has the following requirement
       1) 5 Buttons on top (News, events, offers, maps and feed)
       2) A view that dynamically changes based on the above selection.

    ```
    -Clicking on News, events,offers launches a UIWebview and changes the loadString via the application delegate. Clicking on Map or Feed, launches two different views.
    ```

What I have tried so far is:
1)I have a tabbarcontoller which has its first tab set to to a generic view controller.
2) On load the view controller calls the view with the 5 buttons so application is starting correctly
3) Clicking on (News, events, offers) opens another view controller which has a UIWebView and displays the proper url. There are buttons on top which allows them to switch between 5 functionality. When the user clicks on maps or feed, two different views are loaded as subviews accordingly. However, if i try doing that from the parent page, the views dont appear

To add to my problem if i click on the main tabbar (Home, photos or setting) the tabs are switching views but when I revert to the home tab, it should display the parent view with the 5 buttons.

The first view is being displayed but it is slightly moved up. In the bottom between the view and the tab bar there is small space where the last viewed UIWebview can be seen. So its not removing the previous views. Also navigating using one of the five buttons again opens the view again but the main tab bar is now hidden :(

Can anyone offer some help.

cheers,

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to take your all TabbarController view as Navigation controller. So you can navigate between views without any problem. Take your 3 main view (Home, Photos, Settings) as NavigationController so when you tap any of the tab you will have rootviewController and you can navigate to any view from that tabs.

Hope this help.

Comment: If it is helped you then you can mark it answer so other user can use this answer as well.

Comment: Strange earlier post has been cut short. I had replied saying that my problem is i have two sets of navigation controller to deal with. One is the main navigation relating to the tab bar and the second one is controlling the navigation within one of the views that is launched when one of the tabs is clicked. I need to make sure when the first tab is clicked the second navigation is reset. thanks